# WxPython widget missplaced after hide() & show()

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to build a GUI for a school project for Boolean expressions evaluation. This program takes a string as an input `A^B` and shows it's truth table in the GUI with a Grid widget.

For some reasons (don't want to make this post too long) I need to Hide() and Show() a panel with the only widget it has (the grid) but whenever I call Hide() and Show() the panel is placed on the top-left corner of the parent panel.

Let me clarify using some pictures:[image: Working as it should, panel in place]

The panel that I want to hide is the gray one just below the disabled TextCtrl widget and, as you can see, I placed it where I wanted to. Now let's see after hide() and show()

[image: Wrong place]

Now the panel has been moved to the upper left corner of the screen.

This is how I'm implementing the panel:

```
    #Answer box panel
    self.panel_resp = sp.ScrolledPanel(midPan, -1) # midpan is the parent panel (blue)
    self.panel_resp.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFFF')
    resp_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.panel_resp.SetSizer(resp_sizer)
    self.panel_resp.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.panel_resp.SetupScrolling()
    self.vbox1.Add(self.panel_resp, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,
                   border=10)
    self.vbox1.Add((-1,10))

    self.panel_resp.Hide()
```

Now, whenever I click the 'Evaluar' button, I make the following statement:

`self.panel_resp.Show()`

And the panel shows up in that corner.

Any idea on why is this happening?

I didn't want to fill this post with my code since it's quite huge but I'll gladly answer any questions about it, I just posted that part since I think that's the only important one.

Comment: separate from below: have you made sure you didn't any exceptions in that part of the code? i have seen where an exception will prevent it from getting to the part of the code where it does the layout. the app will still run though and process other events. unless you are starting it from a python console, it may not be obvious anything is wrong.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Yes, no exceptions at all, not even after invoking the hide() / show() action.

Answer (score 0):

I think Show() just makes hidden components visible. Assuming self.vbox1 is the sizer for midpan, try doing a `self.vbox1.Layout()` manually to tell it to move everything to the right spot manually.